# How are apostrophes/character literals parsed in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, lexical

I'm trying to write something that reads Lambda expressions and outputs a beta reduced version. Lambdas will be typed as follows : \variable -> expression and applications will be of the form (expression) (expression). So if '\' is found at the beginning of the string it knows to process a Lambda and if '(' is found it knows to process an application.

I have a type for Lambda Expressions defined:

```
data Expression = Variable String
                | Lambda Expression Expression 
                | Apply Expression Expression
```

Here's my first attempt at writing a function for reading the input

```
processInput :: String -> Expression
processInput ('\':input) = processLambda input
processInput ('(':input) = processApply input
processInput str         = Variable str
```

When I try to load this function I get

```
lexical error in string/character literal at ':'
```

So I tried using guards instead:

```
processInput input
    | head input == '\'                      = processLambda (tail input)
    | head input == '('                      = processApply (tail input)
    | otherwise                              = Variable input
```

But got

```
lexical error in string/character literal at character ' '
```

I have no idea what's wrong with either of these functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backslash is a special character in string and character literals. You use to represent non-printable characters, line breaks and characters that would otherwise have special meaning in a literal. For example `'\n'` is a line break `'\b'` is a back space and `'\''` is a single quote (without the `\`, the second ' would be seen as the end of the character literal).

So when you write `'\'`, the lexer sees the start of a character literal, followed by an escaped `'`. Now it expects another `'` to close the character literal, but gets a colon instead, causing the error.

To represent a backslash as a character literal, you escape the backslash with another backslash like this: `'\\'`.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash is the escape character so it needs to be doubled up to represent a single backslash: `'\\'`.

```hs
processInput ('\\':input) = processLambda input
...

-- or...
processInput input
    | head input == '\\'                      = processLambda (tail input)
...
```